# Change the text of commerce stock

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can someone please help me. My knowledge in jquery/js is very limited. I'm getting stuck on how to do this.

I'd like to change the text of "Out of stock" to "In stock" but this will only applied when the key is "1".

Those are wrapped in div. eg.

```
<div class="in-stock">In stock</div>
<div class="out-stock">Out of stock</div>
<div class="override-stock">1</div>
```

I don't want to display the "out-stock" as "Out of stock" when the key is "1", I want it to be "In stock" also. Please note that I've been using a multiple variations on each stock.

The "override-stock" div has a key inside which is "1" and "0".

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.override-stock').text(function(){
    if ($(this).text('1')) {
      $('.out-stock').text().replace('Out of stock', 'In stock');
    };
  });
});
```

Please help. Thank you so much!!

Comment: Where is the text that is either `1` or `0`

Comment: Sorry, the key is inside the "override-stock" div. I have edited the article. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close, `.text` takes a value to set, if you want to get the value, simply call it `.text()`

```
$(".out-stock").text(function() {
    return $(this).next(".override-stock").text() == "1" ? "In Stock" : "Out of Stock";
});
```

And since you're changing the text on `.out-stock` - you want the `text` function to be on that - then simply check for `1` or `0` and return the desired text.

Comment: Thank you so much for that, but it when I'm trying to select into the other variation, then it's getting back to the previous one.

Comment: @user3045620 -- Not sure I understand what you mean... this logic only applies once on page load - it wont pick up any page changes.